# How to make Hyperlink.Visible=False if Hyperlink.Text = 0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink, repeater, visible

I am trying to hide Hyperlink visibility in Repeater if there isn't any Text value in Hyperlink. Something like this:

```
Protected Sub rptReferenca_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptReferenca.ItemDataBound
    Dim lnkThumb As HyperLink = CType(rptReferenca.FindControl("lnkThumb"), HyperLink)
    If lnkThumb.Text = 0 Then
        lnkThumb.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

But of course it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
Dim lnkThumb As HyperLink = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lnkThumb"), HyperLink)
If lnkThumb.Text.Length = 0 Then
    lnkThumb.Visible = False
End If
```

Need to extract the control from the RepeaterItemEventArgs and check the **Length** of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
If lnkThumb.Text = 0 Then
```

...to this:

```
If lnkThumb.Text.Length = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how VB handles this but you are checking a string against an int.

Maybe

```
If lnkThumb.Text = "0" Then
    lnkThumb.Visible = False
End If
```